# Reading an Oracle Lite ODB file without Oracle Lite

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to extract the data from an Oracle Lite ODB file without installing Oracle Lite?  Is there a reader out there which will let me browse and copy the data?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export the data using the OLLOAD utility, which is part of, but should not require the installation of, Oracle Lite.

[OLLOAD Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12095_01/doc.10302/e12548/cdbtools.htm#BABIIJGF)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tables you need, you do need Oracle Lite completely. You have to however have the webtogo.jar on your classpath. Then you can simply write a small java program to connect via JDBC to the ODB and extract the data you need.